# Evaluation of simple integral

Tags: calculus

Let $-2<a<0$. How to evaluate the integral $\int x^{a}dx$?

Comment: How do you evaluate this for positive $a$?

Comment: $a=-1$ is a special case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a=-1$ we have $\int x^adx=\int \frac{1}{x}dx=\ln(x)+c.$

Thus $$\int x^a dx=\begin{cases} \frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}+c_1 & \text{for $a\neq -1$}, \\ \ln(x)+c_2 & \text{for $a=-1$.}\end{cases}$$